# Unable to Install Apps Despite Plenty of Free Space

Tags: iphone, ios

According to Settings, I (should) have around 32 GB of free space and yet I get "Your device does not have enough available storage to install this app" error.

I have no clue as why this is happening in the first place.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

- iPhone 8 Plus (MQ8L2TU/A)
- iOS 12.1.4 (16D57)

Comment: @Steve Chambers, did you ever find a solution to this problem of yours?

Answer (score 2):

That is odd, to say the least. I am *guessing* here that somehow storage is fragmented and there is not enough *contiguous* free space.

I would do a "backup, wipe and restore."

In other words, plug your phone into your computer and back it up locally (set a backup password so the backup retains your saved passwords). Once that is done go into settings > general > reset > erase all content and settings, and wipe the phone. Once that is done restore it from the backup you just created.

I have found that this frees up space on an iPhone, presumably removing temporary files and the like and, I am thinking, that it will solve your not enough space error.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts... I just didn’t want to reset my phone. I’ll wait a bit longer for other answers too to see if I have any other options, but thanks!